# In sonata admin how can we have multiple levels child admins

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-3.4, sonata

I have a need for multiple tiers of admins. The first parent -> child tier works great, but it seems that I'm not able to add a third.

For instance, my structure looks like:

Grandparent
  -> Parent
    -> Child

The parent "grandparent" admin with a child "parent" admin works great. But, when I try to add the third tier to the tab menu, I see:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("unable to find the route
>   `sonata.admin.grandparent|sonata.admin.parent|sonata.admin.child.list`").

I'm not really familiar enough with the inner workings to figure this one out....any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Did you use `cache:clear` ?

Comment: Having done this now more times I can confirm, not clearing the cache will cause this error. Thank you for the response! I can't think of too many things in Symfony that require caches to be cleared to function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## config/services.yaml

```
App\Admin\ParentAdmin:
calls:
    - [addChild, ['@App\Admin\ChildAdmin', 'parent']]
App\Admin\GrandParentAdmin:
calls:
    - [addChild, ['@App\Admin\ParentAdmin', 'grandParent']]
```

Not sure if the above works but then you've GrandParent -> Parent -> Child. [More information.](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/child_admin.html)

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm honestly not sure what I was doing wrong but I shifted code around for a long time and eventually it just started working. This is the correct answer, and it's working for me, thanks!